# JQuery Accordion SubMenu/Nested not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using JQuery Accordion and it works as it should and opens and closes fine....BUT I want to add an accordion submenu and this doesn't work nor styles either.

My libraries:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
```

I added this test:

```
<p><a href="#">TEST MAIN MENU</a></p>
<div>

<h3><a href="#">Sub header</a></h3>
<div>sub content here</div>

</div>

and "Sub header" is not styled as a header nor it wraps up the div below it like "TEST MAIN MENU" does...

On the <head> I have this:

<script>
      $(function() {
            $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
                  active: false,
            autoHeight: false,
            collapsible: true,
            alwaysOpen: false
            });
      });

      function collapseAll() {
    $("#accordion")
        .filter(":has(.ui-state-active)")
        .accordion("activate", -1);
    $(".ui-accordion-header").blur();
}

</script>
```

`All I need is to make "<h3><a href="#">Sub header</a></h3>"` a collapsable div too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want accordion within an accordion then [this is your solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/qdSu5/)

By the way, when you say "#accordion" in js code, jQuery will try to find an element with id="accordion" and apply the styles to it. In the html that you have currently posted you have no such element.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a submenu in an accordion.

"and "Sub header" is not styled as a header", Where is the CSS? What do you mean not styled as a header?

Can you give an example of what it is you want?

Comment: This answer contains 2 questions. And why do you say that you cannot have a submenu? Please justify.

Comment: Ref: Can you give an example of what it is you want? ... I basically want to add a DIV inside the the current collapsable div ... So you click on parent header .... div opens ... and you get another Header ... you click and you can see the content.

Comment: @Pencho: Ya sure, you can have an accordion in an accordion, but it isn't really a sub-accordion and it doesn't really make sense to use an accordion for this. Maybe my answer was a little badly formulated. He seems to be looking for a collapse-able menu rather. Post your fiddle as answer?